# Listbox inside listbox with binding data

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-8, listbox

Is possible make Listbox inside another listbox? Both listbox have binding same data only second listbox has something added. I dont get any error only data in second listbox(inside first) arent showing or binding not working I dont know. Data to first listbox are binding OK. My sample:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <ListBox x:Name="lbTransitNow" FontSize="13" ItemsSource="{Binding  MyDataForTransit}">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate >
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid x:Name="gridTodayBtn">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbTransitStart" Foreground="Black" Grid.Column="0"
                                             Text="{Binding Lines_departure_time}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbTransitEnd" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Lines_arrival_time}"
                                               Grid.Column="1"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbTransitTravelTime" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Lines_travelTime}"
                                               Grid.Column="2"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbPrice" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Lines_price}"
                                               Grid.Column="3"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbTransitKm" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Lines_km}"
                                               Grid.Column="4"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbTransitNumber" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Lines_name}"
                                               Grid.Column="5"/>
                            <Image x:Name="imgMoreInfo" Source="layoutGraphics/b5.png" Grid.Column="6" Width="40" Height="40" Tapped="imgMoreInfo_Tapped"  Tag="{Binding}"></Image>

                            <ListBox x:Name="lbTransitNowSub" FontSize="13" ItemsSource="{Binding  MyDataForTransit}">
                                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                                    </Style>
                                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate >
                                        <Grid x:Name="gridTodayBtn">
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />

                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbTransitStart" Foreground="Black" Grid.Column="0"
                                             Text="{Binding Lines_departure_time}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbTransitEnd" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Lines_arrival_time}"
                                               Grid.Column="1"/>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbTransitTravelTime" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Lines_travelTime}"
                                               Grid.Column="2"/>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbPrice" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Lines_price}"
                                               Grid.Column="3"/>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbTransitKm" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Lines_km}"
                                               Grid.Column="4"/>
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbTransitNumber" Foreground="Black" Text="{Binding Lines_name}"
                                               Grid.Column="5"/>
                                            <Image x:Name="imgMoreInfo" Source="layoutGraphics/b5.png" Grid.Column="6" Width="40" Height="40" Tapped="imgMoreInfo_Tapped"  Tag="{Binding}"></Image>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>

  public ObservableCollection<BindingData> _myDataForTransit = new ObservableCollection<BindingData>();
    public ObservableCollection<BindingData> MyDataForTransit
    {
        get { return _myDataForTransit; }
        set { _myDataForTransit = value; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(null, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

 _myDataForTransit.Add(new BindingData
            {
                myData...
            });
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("MyDataForTransit");
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly , your approach is not right in place of this you can use collectionViewsource which can be used to implement the grouped data.

cause of not binding is because your second Listbox is in Datatemplate of First Listbox so its DataContext is being set to the DataContext of the Parent that is **MyDataForTransit** and this collection does not contain the collection **MyDataForTransit** to which your second listBox is Binded so your Second listbox is not Showing anything.

For checking this make a collection in your BindingData Class and Bind Second ListBox ItemsSource to this Collection you will Find That it is working.
actually in wpf there is property called relativeSource which can be easily set to your class/page/usercontrol but in windows 8 i am not able to do that.
hope it will help you somehow..